# how to add '+' character after space in flexible string php?

Tags: php, string

i need to add '+' character after space in my string. For example:

```
$str = "hello world helloo worldd" -> "+hello +world +helloo +worldd".
```

String is flexible. How can i do in php. Thanks for helps

Answer (score 2):

You only need to replace space  for space&plus `+` (and probably add `+` to the beginning of string).

```
$str = 'hello world helloo worldd';
echo '+' . str_replace(' ', ' +', $str); // returns '+hello +world +helloo +worldd'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:-

```
$v = 'hello world helloo worldd';
$v = '+'. str_replace(' ', ' +', $v);
echo $v;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using str_replace PHP function. 
For example, to replace your string "hello world helloo worldd"....

```
$stringValue = 'hello world helloo worldd';
echo '+' . str_replace(' ', ' +', $stringValue);
```

Look at PHP official documentation if you need.... http://php.net/str_replace